# Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $p_0$, show that total derivative of $f$ at $p_0$ is unique

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations

Let $R\subseteq \Bbb{R}^m$ be an open subset, and let $f\colon R\to\Bbb{R}^n$ be a function. Let $p_0\in R$ be a given point. Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $p_0$. Show that the total derivative of $f$ at $p_0$ is uniquely determined.

---

Hint given was to work with 2 linear transformations and show that the limit of this map is the zero map, not sure what to do with this hint.

Comment: If the difference between two maps is the zero map, then the two maps are already the same. So show that if two linear maps satisfy the definition of the total derivative, then their difference is the zero map.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Using definition I am able to get A1 and A2, 2 linear transformation, how do I show that the difference is a zero map?

Comment: Consider the limits of $\frac{f(p)-f(p_0)-A_1(p-p_0)}{\vert p-p_0\vert}$ and $\frac{f(p)-f(p_0)-A_2(p-p_0)}{\vert p-p_0\vert}$ as $p\to p_0$. What can you say about the limit of their difference?

Comment: The limit of their difference should equate to 0? But I just can't wrap my head why it is so and how do I form the the 2 limits you provided?

Comment: The two limits are zero by definition. When we say "$f$ is differentiable at $p_0$ with total derivative $A_1$", that's just a different way to say that the above limit is $0$. Or do you have a different definition of differentiability?

Comment: Sorry still very new to this topic, does that mean since both limit is 0 the difference of the 2 limits is zero and thus $A_1$ - $A_2$ = 0 and thus $A_1$ = $A_2$  ? Is this line of thinking correct?

Comment: In principle, yes. But the tricky part is proving that from $\frac{f(p)-f(p_0)-A_1(p-_0)}{\vert p-p_0\vert}-\frac{f(p)-f(p_0)-A_2(p-_0)}{\vert p-p_0\vert}\to0$ it follows that $A_1-A_2=0$. You first have to simplify the large difference term, and then use the fact that for all linear maps $L$ you can find a positive number $M$ such that $\vert L(x)\vert\leq M\vert x\vert$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda, \mu: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ linear transformations such that
$$
\label{eq1}
\lim_{h \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{\Vert f(p_0+h)- f(p_0) -\lambda (p_0)\Vert}{\Vert h \Vert}=0 \quad \quad (1)
$$
and
$$
\lim_{h \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{\Vert f(p_0+h)- f(p_0) -\mu (p_0)\Vert}{\Vert h \Vert}=0. \quad \quad (2)
$$

Set $d(h)=f(p_0+h)-f(p_0).$ Hence we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{h \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{ \Vert \lambda (h)- \mu(h) \Vert}{\Vert h \Vert} &=& \lim_{h \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{ \Vert \lambda (h)-d(h)+d(h)- \mu(h) \Vert}{\Vert h \Vert} \\
 &\leq & \lim_{h \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{ \Vert \lambda (h)- d(h) \Vert}{\Vert h \Vert}+\lim_{h \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{ \Vert d (h)- \mu(h) \Vert}{\Vert h \Vert} = 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Where the last equality is a consequence of (1) and (2).

Now, it should be clear that $\lim_{h \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{ \Vert \lambda (h)- \mu(h) \Vert}{\Vert h \Vert}=0. \quad \quad (3)$

Now lets prove that $\lambda (x) = \mu (x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^m.$

The equality holds for $x = \mathbf{0}$. So, suppose $x \neq \mathbf{0}.$

We shall prove that $\Vert \mu (x)- \lambda (x) \Vert < \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. So pick an arbitrary positive $\varepsilon.$ By (3), there's a $\delta>0$ such that
$$0<\Vert h \Vert < \delta \Longrightarrow \frac{\Vert \lambda (h) - \mu (h) \Vert}{\Vert h \Vert}<\frac{\varepsilon}{\Vert x \Vert}.$$

Now pick a $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < \Vert tx \Vert <\delta.$ Hence for $h=tx$ we have by linearity of $\lambda$ and $\mu,$ $$\frac{\varepsilon}{\Vert x \Vert}>\frac{\Vert \lambda (tx)- \mu (tx) \Vert}{\Vert tx \Vert}=\frac{|t|\Vert \lambda (x)- \mu (x) \Vert}{|t|\Vert x \Vert}=\frac{\Vert \lambda (x)- \mu (x) \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert}=\frac{\Vert \lambda (x)- \mu (x)\Vert }{\Vert x \Vert}.$$

Now, multiply the last inequality by $\Vert x \Vert.$